# Show dialog until background process completed

Tags: android, multithreading, dialog

I'm doing background processing. Meanwhile, i want to show a circular progressbar to the user. When the background process completes, i want to hide the circular progressbar. However when i run somethign after showDialog() it disappears. How can show this dialog while background process is going on?

MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ProgressBar progressBar;
    int pStatus = 0;
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    public static Dialog circularProgressBarDialog;
    public static Thread circularProgressBarThread;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        circularProgressBarDialog = new Dialog(this);
        circularProgressBarDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_circular_progressbar);
        progressBar = circularProgressBarDialog.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        circularProgressBarDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        circularProgressBarDialog.setCancelable(false);


        if(circularProgressBarThread != null && circularProgressBarThread.isAlive()){
            circularProgressBarThread.interrupt();
        }
        circularProgressBarThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (pStatus <=100) {
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            progressBar.setProgress(pStatus);
                            Log.d("tarik","pStatus : " + pStatus);
                            if(pStatus++ >= 100){
                                pStatus = 0;
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(20);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }
        });
        circularProgressBarThread.start();


        new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                circularProgressBarDialog.show(); // dialog appears

                /* dialog disappears when this for loop runs!! WHY !!!!  */
                for (int i = 0; i < 200000; i++) {
                    Log.d("heavy work","1");
                }
                circularProgressBarDialog.dismiss();
                circularProgressBarThread.interrupt();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

custom_progressbar_drawable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="-90"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toDegrees="270" >

    <shape
        android:shape="ring"
        android:useLevel="false" >
        <gradient
            android:centerY="0.5"
            android:endColor="#FA5858"
            android:startColor="#0099CC"
            android:type="sweep"
            android:useLevel="false" />
    </shape>

</rotate>
```

dialog_circular_progressbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:indeterminate="false"
            android:max="100"
            android:progress="0"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_progressbar_drawable"
            android:secondaryProgress="0" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I recommend you to use AsyncTask which is more inherent with Android ecosystem instead of threads and runnable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using setCancelabl(false) to the progressdialog.
You can also use Asynchronous  task for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 200000; i++) {
     Log.d("heavy work","1");
 }
```

with some real heavy work. A loop from 0 to 200000 doesn't seem too heavy for me. Try with:

```
Thread.sleep(5000)
```

or something to add some delay representing a heavy work. Remember that real progress bars should be updated with real progress or set indeterminate to true otherwise. You can accomplish a real representation of your progress by setting progress inside the "work" block. Remember to call runOnUiThread() if you update views out of the UI thread.